# Expander Style questions

Tags: wpf, xaml, expander

iam a newby in WPF and i need help again...

I have an expander with Round Corners, but i don't like this and i want rectangular corners. Can anyone tell me how i can solve this problem?
This is my expander
.. Style:

```
<Style x:Key="exp_AInfo_Style" TargetType="Expander">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="18,5,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="259"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="29"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="155"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and the Object:

```
       <Expander x:Name="exp_AInfo" Header="Allgemeine Info's" 
            Style="{StaticResource exp_AInfo_Style}" Height="116"
            >
            <Expander.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pct/expander.png" Opacity="0.9"/>
            </Expander.Background>
            <Grid Height="112">
                <!--many many objects-->
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
```

Thanks 4 help

Comment: I've removed my answer, but see this SO post and see if you can adjust it to fit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738711/label-and-expander-control-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the CornerRadius of the ToggleButton ControlTemplate.

There you go:

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton"
             TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
              CornerRadius="0,0,0,0"
              BorderThickness="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black">

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                  Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandededArrow">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                  Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid>
                <Path x:Name="CollapsedArrow"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>
                <Path x:Name="ExpandededArrow"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Data="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z">
                    <Path.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                    </Path.Fill>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="ContentRow"
                       Height="0" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              BorderThickness="1"
                              CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1"
                               StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                               EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                            </Border.Background>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                        Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ToggleButton.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </ToggleButton.Background>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="4"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Content"
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                                  CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentRow"
                                Property="Height"
                                Value="{Binding DesiredHeight, ElementName=Content}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter> 
    </Style>
```

Comment: uuhfffg... I have expected that the solution is 2 line code